# Is there a device that will accept 2 hdmi inputs and output a single, 3d signal with one source for each eye?

Tags: video, 3d, hdmi

I am trying to create a DIY dualplay setup. I would like to take 2 PS4s and combine their output into a 3d signal. Then, with modified active shutter glasses, two people could simultaneously watch one of the sources each on the same display at the same time.

My display can decode Top and Bottom, Side by Side, and frame packed 3d signals.

I think either a tiler that accepts 2 sources would work, or some other device that can alternate frames from the sources.

Matrox makes a device for approximately $500 that is SDI only, not HDMI, so I would need 3 converters at $200-300 a pop, which is outside my budget.

Any suggestions?